# react-image-magnifiers image width auto

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react-material-ui-carousel to show different images with in available height and width auto. Everything is working but i have to implement Glass Magnify image on hover. when using
react-image-magnifiers always take full width. i want to render image according to their aspect ratio with width : auto. Here is my code. images aspect ratio is too much different

```
             <Carousel
                index={currentSlide}
                onChange={(value) => setCurrentSlide(value)}
                indicators={false}
                navButtonsAlwaysInvisible={false}
                navButtonsProps={{ style: { display: "none" } }}
                animation='slide'
                autoPlay={false}
                // timeout={3000}
              >
                {imgs.map((item, i) => (
                  <div
                    key={i}
                    style={{
                      width: "100%",
                      display: "flex",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    <GlassMagnifier
                      imageSrc={item.img}
                      imageAlt={`Image ${i}`}
                      magnifierSize='30%'
                      cursorStyle='zoom-in'
                      className='image'
                      style={{
                        width: "auto",
                        maxWidth: "auto",
                        height: "100%",
                        maxHeight: "65vh",
                        objectFit: "contain",
                      }}
                    />

                    {/* <img
                      src={item.img}
                      style={{
                        width: "auto",
                        maxHeight: "65vh",
                        cursor: "pointer",
                      }}
                     
                    /> */}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Carousel>
```